# How to terminate the SQL server agent job after X minutes?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a job running on MS SQL Server under SQL Agent. The job basically runs a dtsx package and it is running every 5 minutes. Is there way that the job automatically terminates if it is running more than 4 minutes? Normally the  job completes within 3 seconds.

Comment: this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278359/sql-agent-set-a-max-execution-time

Comment: we faced a similar problem with a job, which runs several hours and has to be terminated at a certain time. After all we implemented a second job, which evaluates if the corresponding job is still running and then executes a kill statement. This can be extended by the execution duration and so on - but otherwise we did not find any other handy soultion for this problem.

Comment: @Tyron78 could you help me with the code of 'second job' please. I need to kill my job if it is running more than 4 minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following approach might to solve this issue (we got it a bit differently - we have a stored procedure which evaluates, if the job is running beforehand and then performs the exec): you can get the runtime of the required job via a SQL query:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT sj.name, sja.start_execution_date
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sja.start_execution_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
  WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
     AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
     AND sj.name LIKE '%myJobName%'
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, start_execution_date, GETDATE())/60. AS RunTimeMinutes
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

This you can load into a variable. In the next step you can do something like:

```
IF @MyVar >= 4 THEN EXEC '[msdb].[dbo].[sp_stop_job] N' + char(39) + 'myJobName' + char(39)
```